# code is not compiling

Tags: c++, linker-errors

```
//cstack.h
# ifndef _STACK_H__
#define _STACK_H__

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

template< class Type ,int Size = 3>
class cStack
{
 Type *m_array;
 int m_Top;
 int m_Size;

public:
    cStack();
    cStack(const Type&);
    cStack(const cStack<Type,Size> &);
    int GetTop()const;
    bool Is_Full()const;
    bool Is_Empty()const;
    void InsertValue(const Type&);
    void RemeoveValue();
    void show();  
    ~cStack();
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &, const cStack<Type,Size> &);
};

// iam writing only one function defination because linking is because of this function
template< class Type,int Size >
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream &os, const cStack<Type,Size> &s)
{
 for( int i=0; i<=s.GetTop();i++)
 {
  os << s.m_array[i];
 }
 return os;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include "cStack.h"
#include <string>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
 cStack<int> sobj(1);
 std::cout << sobj;
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class cStack<int,3> const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABV?$cStack@H$02@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: Can you provide the code from `main()` (or maybe `_main()`) where the function is called?

Comment: main()
{
cStack<int> sobj(1);
}

Comment: sorry here is my main
main
{
cStack<int> sobj(1);
std::cout << sobj;

Comment: user323422: put the whole of main() into the body of your question.

Comment: Can people be a bit more friendly to new users please. Also while you're adding then main contents place a comment in which file the code lives as this is vital for linker-error fixing.

Comment: Can you edit the title of this question so that it is a bit more precise ?

Answer (score 6):

**35.16** [Why do I get linker errors when I use template friends?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16)

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &, const cStack<Type, Size> &);
```

Mark the function as template functions

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream &, const cStack<Type, Size> &);
```

And the compiler will be happy.
And put the function definition before the class definition.

```
template< class Type ,int Size>
class cStack;

template< class Type ,int Size >
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const cStack<Type,Size> &s)
{
    for( int i=0; i<=s.GetTop();i++)
    {
        os << s.m_array[i];
    }
    return os;
}


template< class Type ,int Size = 3>
class cStack
{
    Type *m_array;
    int m_Top;
    int m_Size;
public:
    cStack() {}
     //...
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream &, const cStack<Type, Size> &);
};
```

Comment: More info: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16 (I'd rather go with the suggestion at the end.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the linker can't find your function. Place all the code in the the header file.

Comment: Is this the same header as the one containing cStack definition? Probably you need to show us whole .cpp that contains your `main`

Comment: #include"cstack.h"
main()
{cStack<int> sobj(1);
 
 std::cout << sobj;
}

Comment: Does "cstack.h" contains both class definition and template method implementation? Does it help if you move your template method implementation just above your `main` in cpp file? Are you sure that code in the question is your actual code (no typos)?

Answer (score 0):

It's compiling, it's just not linking.  (I know, that's not a big help.)  You don't have a place where the function template is being instantiated.  Do you have a main() somewhere that tries to use this stream insertion operator?

Comment: main
{
cStack<int> sobj(1);
std::cout << sobj;

}

Answer (score 0):

[snip]

The following works on windows with Visual Studio 2005

```
template <class Type, int Size = 3 >
class cStack 
{
    // ....

    template<class Type>
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, const cStack<Type> &s);
};

template<class Type>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const cStack<Type> &s)
{
    for( int i=0; i < s.GetTop();i++)
    {
        os << s.m_array[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```